# Print index and new index of array java

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, heap

So my code is almost complete, i just need a way to print out the index and when i reorganize my heap, to print out that original index but in the new spot. My heap is organized to print out the minimum value but when I try to print out the index, i just print out the new index.

Here is my java code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

/** Class BinaryHeap **/
class BinaryHeap    
{
/** The number of children each node has **/
private static final int d = 2;
private int heapSize;
private int[] heap;


/** Constructor **/    
public BinaryHeap(int capacity)
{
    heapSize = 0;
    heap = new int[capacity + 1];
    Arrays.fill(heap, -1);       
}

/** Function to check if heap is empty **/
public boolean isEmpty( )
{
    return heapSize == 0;
}

/** Check if heap is full **/
public boolean isFull( )
{
    return heapSize == heap.length;
}

/** Clear heap */
public void makeEmpty( )
{
    heapSize = 0;
}   

/** Function to  get index parent of i **/
private int parent(int i) 
{
    return (i - 1)/d;
}

/** Function to get index of k th child of i **/
private int kthChild(int i, int k) 
{
    return d * i + k;
}

/** Function to insert element */
public void insert(int x)
{
    if (isFull( ) )
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Overflow Exception");
    /** Percolate up **/
    heap[heapSize++] = x;
    heapifyUp(heapSize - 1);
}

/** Function to find least element **/
public int findMin( )
{
    if (isEmpty() )
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Underflow Exception");           
    return heap[0];
}

/** Function to delete min element **/
public int deleteMin()
{
    int keyItem = heap[0];
    newID(0);
    delete(0);
    return keyItem;
}

/** Function to delete element at an index **/
public int delete(int ind)
{
    if (isEmpty() )
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Underflow Exception");
    int keyItem = heap[ind];
    heap[ind] = heap[heapSize - 1];
    heapSize--;
    heapifyDown(ind);        
    return keyItem;
}

/** Function heapifyUp  **/
private void heapifyUp(int childInd)
{
    int tmp = heap[childInd];    
    while (childInd > 0 && tmp < heap[parent(childInd)])
    {
        heap[childInd] = heap[ parent(childInd) ];
        childInd = parent(childInd);
    }                   
    heap[childInd] = tmp;
}

/** Function heapifyDown **/
private void heapifyDown(int ind)
{
    int child;
    int tmp = heap[ ind ];
    while (kthChild(ind, 1) < heapSize)
    {
        child = minChild(ind);
        if (heap[child] < tmp)
            heap[ind] = heap[child];
        else
            break;
        ind = child;
    }
    heap[ind] = tmp;
}

/** Function to get smallest child **/
private int minChild(int ind) 
{
    int bestChild = kthChild(ind, 1);
    int k = 2;
    int pos = kthChild(ind, k);
    while ((k <= d) && (pos < heapSize)) 
    {
        if (heap[pos] < heap[bestChild]) 
            bestChild = pos;
        pos = kthChild(ind, k++);
    }    
    return bestChild;
}

/** Function to print heap **/
public void printHeap()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < heapSize; i++){
        System.out.print(heap[i] +" ");
        printID(i);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public void printID(int i)
{
    System.out.println("Sequence ID: " + (i+1));
} 
public void newID(int i)
{
    int x = i;
}  
 public void printnewID(int i)
{
    System.out.println("Sequence ID: " + (i+1));
}       
}

/** Class BinaryHeapTest **/
public class BinaryHeapTest
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Binary Heap Test\n\n");
    /** Make object of BinaryHeap **/
    BinaryHeap bh = new BinaryHeap(101);  
    BinaryHeap bh2 = new BinaryHeap(101);          

    int check = 0;
    int[] array = new int[100]; //Make 100 numbers
    int[] ID = new int[100]; // ID array
    Random rng = new Random();
    for(int i= 0; i < array.length; i++){
        ID[i] = (i + 1);
        array[i] = rng.nextInt(39);
        bh.insert(array[i]);
        check++;
    }
    System.out.println("Heap 1 : ");    
    bh.printHeap();
    System.out.println("Number of heap values = " + check);
    for (int j = 1; j <= 100; j++){
       bh2.insert(bh.deleteMin());
    }
    System.out.println("Heap 2 : ");    
    bh2.printHeap();            
}
}
```

[image: Example of first heap output]

[image: Example of 2nd heap output]

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a sample of the output you get vs. the output you want?

Comment: printnewID() seem to be doing absolutely nothing. If your code runs now then removing that method should make no effects. I don't see the need for import java.util.*

Comment: Added pictures of my output, The Sequence ID is the index of the first array, but it prints out new index in the 2nd array, I'd like it to print out the original index of those numbers. For Example, value 1 in the 2nd heap should print out ID of 5 as that was the ID in the first heap. and so on. It does this from 0-100 in sequence ID, I just couldn't get the full output of each heap in 1 picture.

Comment: The way I would do this is by creating an inner class with constructor: `IndexNumPair(int index, int number)` And have a `IndexNumPair[]` array, and just do something like `indexNumPair[i].getNum()` and `indexNumPair[i].getIndex()`. But I'm sure there's a better way, this is just one way. You'd probably have to re-code the heap methods to accommodate.